# How do dog teeth and notches on wings create vortices?

Tags: aerodynamics

According to  [this](https://aerospaceweb.org/question/aerodynamics/q0228.shtml#:%7E:text=A%20dogtooth%20also%20generates%20a,wingtip%20close%20to%20the%20aileron.) link (text right above F-18 picture) there are vortices made from leading edge notches and dog teeth, (2 vortices from notches and 1 from dog teeth). Why is that, and do other things like cuffs create vortices too? What even makes the vortices form, and what direction do they rotate in?

Side note : I am not 100% sure what leading edge notches look like, I cannot find a good picture of them for the life of me. Sorry if that seems like something I should've seen before asking this question. (I know what dog teeth are because I saw the F-14 and F-18 with them, but I still don't know how they would make vortices)

The final little thing I was curious about is this : If you were to take a chunk out of the leading edge of the wing, would that create a singular vortex similar to vortex generators? I'll put a picture to show what I mean. (that rectangle where I circled is what you would cut out of the wing) My theory is that the low pressure on both sides of the cut out piece would pull air toward each other, then the air would collide and make a vortex. [image]

Comment: [Better view](https://www.airplane-pictures.net/photo/109938/166677-usa-navy-mcdonnell-douglas-f-18-f-a-18f-super-hornet/) of the devices.